# How to change the color of placeholder in a Material ui Autocomplete

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

There are two different projects in which an internal library is being used in my team which provides a header in which there is a search box.
In one of the projects, the placeholder text "Search" appears normally

[image]

But in the other project when used with the same third party library, the text appears differently.

[image]

The third party library uses MaterialUI "Autocomplete" to implement the search Bar.

I tried to look for color and opacity properties and tried a few different things with them but none of them had an effect. The properties all look the same, what other property should I try to check ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the color inside the . Something like this in line 36

[image]